# Saving NSString to file

Tags: xcode, saving-data

I am having trouble saving simple website data to file.  I believe the sintax is correct, could someone help me?  When I run it, it shows that it gets the data, but when i quit and open up the file that it is supposed to save to, nothing is in it.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)nextField {

 [timer invalidate];
 startButton.hidden = NO;
 startButton.enabled = YES;
 stopButton.enabled = NO;
 stopButton.hidden = YES;
 stopLabel.hidden = YES;
 label.hidden = NO;
 label.text = @"Press to Activate";

 [nextField resignFirstResponder];

 NSString *urlString = textField.text;

 NSData *dataNew = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]; 

 NSUInteger len = [dataNew length];

 NSString *stringCompare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", len];

 NSLog(@"%@", stringCompare);



 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"websiteone" ofType:@"txt"];  
 if (filePath) {  
  [stringCompare writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
  NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
  NSLog(@"Saving... %@", myText);
 }
 else {
  NSLog(@"cant find the file");
 }


 return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question, but I see 2 problems with your code.  First, the docs for resignFirstResponder say "Never invoke this method directly."  Second, you seem to be trying to save into your own app bundle, and that's a no-no.  Consider your bundle read-only.